# Como alinear listas en columnas con Css?

Tags: html, html5, css, css3

Tengo 4 listas (Empresa , Servicios , Valorar un Servicios y Contactos ) y nesecito mostrarlas en mi pagina como en la imagen pero por supuestos de forma alineada , que debo hacer ???

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Si pudieras dar más detalle del html actual, el tipo de alineación que quieres, etc, sería mejor para ayudarte.

Comment: Si pudieras compartir el html y el css que tienes actualmente o reproducirlo y crear un ejemplo que simule tu situación sería mucho más fácil ayudarte.

Comment: Existen muchas respuestas posibles, o las buenas respuestas son demasiado extensas para este formato. Añade detalles para reducir el conjunto de respuestas o separar un problema que se puede responder en pocos párrafos.

Comment: Por favor pon lo que llevas de código escrito para poder buscar la solución de una manera más fácil, oportuna y concreta.

Answer (score 2):

Podrías poner cada lista en un div, y éstos a su vez en un div padre, definirle un ancho a los hijos y ponerle la propiedad `float:left` desde css a los hijos.

Por ejemplo:

```css
#padre {
  width: 330px;
  height: 300px;
  background-color: black;
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
}
.hijos {
  width: 100px;
  height: 300px;
  float: left;
  margin-right: 5px;
  margin-left: 5px;
  background-color: white;
}
```

```html
<div id="padre">
  <div class="hijos">

  </div>
  <div class="hijos">

  </div>
  <div class="hijos">

  </div>
</div>
```